# How to put rstrip() in list of touple

Tags: python

I have code like

```
query_create_table += '%s %s,' % (ev_fields[i][0],ev_fields[i][1]).rstrip(',')
```

where ev_fields is a list of touples.I don,t want ',' at the last field.So that I am using rstrip() .But it throws error like
       `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'`
 I have tried to put rstrip() otherewhere,but it throws syntax error.How can I use here the rstrip()?

Comment: Which `,` are you talking about? The trailing comma in `'%s %s,'`, or a trailing comma in `ev_fields[i][1]`?

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing a bracket:

```py
>>> print ('%s %s,' % ("A", "B")).rstrip(',')
A B
```

Or simply:

```
>>> print '%s %s' % ("A", "B")
A B
```

If that's not what you mean and the problem is somewhere deeper in `ev_field`, it'd be helpful to see some example code that generates that list.

---

According to your comment you *might* be looking for something like this:

```
s = ""
for i in range(5):
    s += '%s %s, ' % (str(i), str(10 * i))
s = s.strip(', ')

print s
```

Output:

```
0 0, 1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40
```

This can be simplified using `join`:

```
>>> print ', '.join('%s %s' % (str(i), str(10 * i)) for i in range(5))
0 0, 1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40
```

Comment: I have lots of field .I want everywhere , except the last field..Only I want to remove , from last field..

Comment: Then drop the ```rstrip``` in each iteration ```i``` and just do it once when finished: ```query_create_table = query_create_table.rstrip(',')```.

Comment: .join is ok...But I have other query at top of it So, I have to use query_create_table +=   that + i have to use..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.rstrip(',')` for each argument:

```
query_create_table += '%s %s' % (ev_fields[i][0].rstrip(','),ev_fields[i][1].rstrip(','))
```

Comment: it is not working,I have tried already....

Comment: And what error did you get when you tried this?

Comment: no error but it is not removing the ',' from the last field..

Comment: you don't want to have any commas at the end then?  I've edited my answer to remove the comma

Comment: I want ',' for all other field except the end...Only I don,t want ',' at the end...

Comment: Do you have ',' in `ev_fields[i][0]` and `ev_fields[i][1]`?

Comment: no ,so that I have putted by '%s %s,'

Comment: And are you looping over `ev_fields` with `i` as index?

Answer (score 1):

If this is all the loop is doing, you could also use join:

```
query_create_table = ",".join([ "%s %s" % (ev[0],ev[1]) for ev in ev_fields ])
```

Comment: You can use generator as well `query_create_table = ",".join("%s %s" % (ev[0],ev[1]) for ev in ev_fields)` or  `query_create_table = ",".join(("%s %s" % (ev[0],ev[1]) for ev in ev_fields))`

Comment: Thank you, I have learned something, too

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (if I understood you question right):

```
'%s %s,'.rstrip(',') % (ev_fields[i][0],ev_fields[i][1]).rstrip(',')
```

But you shouldn't use `+` for string concatenation in python in first place.
Use generator expression or at least list comprehension and `join` function.

Comment: It is removing ',' from all the field ..I don,t want that ..I want to remove the ',' from the last field only..

Comment: see Simon Fraser answer, if you have to use index variable `i` then you can do something like `query_create_table = ",".join("%s %s" % (ev_fields[i][0], ev_fields[i][1]) for i in xrange(len(ev_fields)))` But I think you don't.

Comment: .join is ok...But I have other query at top of it So, I have to use query_create_table += that + i have to use..

Comment: No, you don't have to, although you can.

Comment: Well i'd use something like `query_create_table = ' '.join((query_create_table, ','.join(...)))` or if you want to, use `+=` with Simon Fraser's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`rstrip()` is a string method, not a tuple method. Try this instead

```
query_create_table += '%s %s,' % (ev_fields[i][0].rstrip(','), ev_fields[i][1].rstrip(','))
```

Or, it's possible that you actually want to remove the `,` in `'%s %s,'`. If so just remove it from the string with no need for `rstrip()`, i.e.

```
query_create_table += '%s %s' % (ev_fields[i][0], ev_fields[i][1])
```

Now, ignore what I just said because you appear to be constructing an SQL query by building your own string via string interpolation. You should instead be using parameterized SQL queries. Instead of

```
query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" % (var1, var2, var3)
cursor.execute(query)
```

you should be doing something like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

where `%s` is a place holder (it may be different for different db engines, e.g. `?`). This ensures that proper escaping and quoting of the parameters takes place, reducing a the chances of there being an SQL injection vulnerability.